# How can I prevent my labels from getting reflected?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, pst-eucl

The left triangle is the image of the right triangle about the vertical line in between them as the mirror.

I only want geometric objects and label position (but excluding their labels) to be reflected. How can I prevent the labels of the left triangle from being reflected?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\Right#1{%
    \pnodes(1,1){#11}(3,1){#12}(1,4){#13}
    \pspolygon(#11)(#12)(#13)
    \uput[180](#11){A}
    \uput[0](#12){B}
    \uput[180](#13){C}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,0)(4,5)
    \Right{A}
    \psscalebox{-1 1}{\Right{B}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output I want to get is as follows.

[image]

### Note

Please don't suggest me to separate the left and right object by defining an individual macro for each because my real scenario needs reflection technique and I also want to adopt the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself!).

### Edit

I tried the following

```
\rput{*0}(!N-#11.x .3 sub N-#11.y){A}
\rput{*0}(!N-#12.x .3 add N-#12.y){B}
\rput{*0}(!N-#13.x .3 sub N-#13.y){C}
```

but it does not help.

I also tried the following but it does not help.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
%\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\def\Right#1{%
    \pnodes(1,1){#11}(3,1){#12}(1,4){#13}
    \pspolygon(#11)(#12)(#13)
    %\rput{*0}(!N-#11.x .3 sub N-#11.y){A}
    %\rput{*0}(!N-#12.x .3 add N-#12.y){B}
    %\rput{*0}(!N-#13.x .3 sub N-#13.y){C}
    \uput[180](#11){A}
    \uput[0](#12){B}
    \uput[180](#13){C}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,0)(4,5)
    \Right{A}
    \pscustom
    {
        \code{-1 1 scale}
        \Right{B}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The macro `\psscalebox` is a box scaling macro. That means the content is save in an lrbox and modified by the given parameters.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I tried with `\code{-1 1 scale}` but it does not help as well.

Comment: I think the package `pst-optic` is more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\newcommand\Right[2][1 1]{%
  \psscalebox{#1}{%
    \pnodes(1,1){#21}(3,1){#22}(1,4){#23}%
    \pspolygon(#21)(#22)(#23)%
    \uput[180](#21){\psscalebox{#1}{A}}%
    \uput[0](#22){\psscalebox{#1}{B}}%
    \uput[180](#23){\psscalebox{#1}{C}}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,0)(4,5)
    \Right{A}
    \Right[-1 1]{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```