# How to follow the DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself) in multidoc?

Tags: lyx, preamble, embedding, lyx-layouts

What is the best way to keep the configurations and same content in different parts of the main document reusable from single location (e.g. from *child document*)?

First idea was to have this structure layout:

```
main_doc.lyx <- partial_doc.lyx <- general_preamble_doc.lyx
```

where `general_preamble_doc.lyx` has only something like `\makenomenclature` or `\usepackage`

Would these scheme imply that the `main_doc.lyx` will also inherit the `general_preamble_doc.lyx` or should I include/input it in the `main_doc.lyx` as well? Should I `\input` or `\include` it?

## Update 1:

*DRY* = Don't Repeat Yourself // sorry guys for confusion, I thought this acronym is already a common sense and unambiguous

Comment: @cfr Don't Repeat Yourself???

Comment: @HarishKumar Oh. I worry more about DRM.

Comment: Implementing a class or a package will help you to get WET and to avoid DRY.

Comment: DRY has been used several times in my post: [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104445/19356), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161779/19356), and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147352/19356).